# Meteor - Allow multiple users to edit a post

Tags: javascript, meteor

- I'm not able to use the node server debugger so I'm posting here to see if I can get a nudge in the right direction.

I am trying to allow multiple users to edit documents created by any of the users within their specific company. My code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

(Server)

```
ComponentsCollection.allow({
  // Passing in the user object (has profile object {company: "1234"}
  // Passing in document (has companyId field that is equal to "1234"
  update: function(userObject, components) { 
    return ownsDocument(userObject, components); 
  }
});
```

(Server)

```
// check to ensure user editing document created/owned by the company
ownsDocument = function(userObject, doc) {
  return userObject.profile.company === doc.companyId;
}
```

The error I'm getting is: Exception while invoking method '/components/update' TypeError: Cannot read property 'company' of undefined

I'm trying to be as secure as possible, though am doing some checks before presenting any data to the user, so I'm not sure if this additional check is necessary. Any advice on security for allowing multiple users to edit documents created by the company would be awesome. Thanks in advance. -Chris

**Update (solution):**

```
// check that the userId specified owns the documents
ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {

  // Gets the user form the userId being passed in
  var userObject = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);

  // Checking if the user is associated with the company that created the document being modified 
  // Returns true/false respectively
  return doc.companyId === userObject.profile.companyId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs, it looks like the first argument to the allow/deny functions is a user ID, not a user document. So you'll have to do `Meteor.users.findOne(userId)` to get to the document first.

Do keep in mind that users can write to their own `profile` subdocument, so if you don't disable that, users will be able to change their own company, allowing them to edit any post. You should move `company` outside of `profile`.

(If you can't use a proper debugger, old-fashioned `console.log` still works. Adding `console.log(userObject)` to `ownsDocument` probably would have revealed the solution.)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Console.log doesn't work within this server function (so I have experienced). Would make my life easier. Thanks for pointing out the doc regarding the userId as the first argument, I missed that and thought I could use anything as the first argument. To disable editing on the profile, I would use the "collection.deny(options)"?

Comment: Yes - see the first section of [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: That code block would be added to the server folder as a seperate file?